# 2 iPads - does that mean double storage?

Tags: ipad, applications, storage

I'm just wondering: if I have two iPads, can I choose which apps go on each of the iPads. The memory is almost full on both. I hope I've explained this clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. I assume you're using the same Apple ID on both iPads (otherwise it isn't an issue at all). Go to the Settings app and choose iTunes & App Store. In the Automatic Downloads section, disable the switch next to 'Apps'. Once you've done this, apps will no longer automatically be installed on this iPad if you install them on the other.

[image]